# Python concurrency performance

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, concurrency, parallel-processing

I'm facing concurrency in Python for the first time with the goal in mind to optimize my script. Basically I have a script which invokes third party jar tools using os.system against some files. My first "procedural" version took about 135 seconds to complete, after using threads (**threading.Thread** and **threading.Queue**) 127 and now switching to multiprocess (**multiprocessing.Process** and **multiprocessing.JoinableQueue**) 113 seconds... but it's still a lot of time... could you give me some feedback and/or point me to an article that may solve my problem?

(I'm using Python 2.7.1 and I would like to avoid 3d party modules)

Comment: That fully depends on what you are trying to do. Since you use jar files and os.system probably the dominating factor in your response time will be in your java application. If you want an answer please give us more information.

Comment: I'm using Google Closure JavaScript compiler

Comment: Have you try subprocess.Popen?

Comment: no... I'm gonna read about it ;)

Comment: What system are you running this on?  And how independently do your threads/processes operate?  The times you give here don't look like what you'd expect if the bottleneck in your code is sequential execution and your concurrency solution is effective.

Answer (score 2):

Many people seem to think that multi-threading will "magically" speed up their application. The performance increase possible from multi-threading depends on several factors: mainly the number of CPU cores and the type of application.

When I say "type of application", Im referring to whether or not it makes sense for your app to be divided into pieces and executed in parallel. You havent given enough info for us to be able to determine that, but you should analyze it and try to determine if it makes sense.

Most CPUs today are multi-core, so threading shouldnt be bound by that, unless you create more threads than cores, so take care with the number of threads you create.

If you're wondering why the multiprocessing (forked processes) goes faster than threading, its most likely due to the Python [Global Interpreter Lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) (GIL) Which basically causes Python multi-threading to not be very performant.

**Update:** If you're compiling (based on your comment: "I'm using Google Closure JavaScript compiler") and want to stick with Python, you should try [SCons](http://www.scons.org/). Its a really cool build tool, whose build scripts are all in Python.